# Elite attribute and damage change with level

Tags: diablo-iii

I haven't played Diablo III much with lower level characters since the difficulty settings were introduced (Normal - Torment) and earlier 4 difficulty levels of Normal - Inferno were removed. 
Recently I was leveling lower level chars, and realized that even Master setting still gives only 2 suffix Elites at earlier levels. This seems to change to 3 suffixes at lvl 50 (player level), unfortunately my HC WD died at lvl 59 from being overaggressive because the game got too easy.

How do the Elite suffixes interact with both **player** and **difficulty** levels?

1. Do they always scale to 3 attributes at player level 50+ and then 4 at level 60+, or is it affected by difficulty in any way
2. Besides their normal attack damage, does the Arcane Enchanted or Molten damage also scale with difficulty level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 1 Affix - Game level 1-29
- 2 Affixes - Game level 30-49
- 3 Affixes - Game level 50-59
- 4 Affixes - Game level 60-70
- Unique mosters (bosses, mini-bosses, keywardens) will have 1-4 Affixes plus random bonuses. For instance, some keywardens have the ability to do a Fire Nova attack. Another may have the ability to call down an Ice Storm.

Some Affixes can only appear on Monsters with a certain level. For instance, Arcane can only appear on Monsters with a level of 31 or higher.

**Question 1** - The number of affixes are scaled only based on the level in the game, not difficulty.
**Question 2** - All damage. no matter if it's an affix or a trap on the map, scales with difficulty.

For more information about the affixes and when they can appear on enemies, [click here](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Monster_Traits_%28Diablo_III%29).